# Duplicate userame in site collection after list import form classic to claims authenticated server

Tags: 2010, export, import, user-accounts, duplicate

I had an list on SharePoint server 2010 enterprise with classic authentication. on the list there was field with usernames

After I migrated (import/export statements below) this list to new server with claims based authentication every user that was on this list get a duplicate entry (on http_://newsite/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx)...

How can I get rid of this duplicates? on AD it's this same account!... full sync does not work :/

old server: export-spweb –identity http_://oldsite/test -ItemUrl Lists/oldlist –path C:\export\x.cmp –includeversion all

new server: import-spweb –identity http_://newsite/test –path C:\export\x.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite -IncludeUserSecurity

Best regards
Roman

Answer (score 1):

As you have probably noticed, claims and classic treat users differently, formatting their login names slightly differently. As a reault when you brought in the site, the classic login names are no longer valid. You can use powershell to loop through the user accounts and remove any that match the classic name format.

I highly recommend trying this on a test environment first!

Comment: Thank You for answer, but what about files/ entries that users with old usernames entered?

Comment: Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx